# OpenJDK default options to always use the server VM

Tags: 12.04, openjdk

I got a warning message:

> jvm uses the client vm, make sure to run `java` with the server vm for best performance by adding `-server` to the command line

In fact, when i run java -version i get:

```
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.3.2) (7u7-2.3.2a-0ubuntu0.12.04.1)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 23.2-b09, mixed mode, sharing)
```

How does one go about and change OpenJDK's defaults to always start under the server VM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have both the client and server VM installed, you just need to change the order of the lines in jvm.cfg to make -server first. You can find jvm.cfg like this:

```
find $(dirname $(dirname $(readlink -f $(which java)))) -name jvm.cfg
```

On my machine, it's `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/jvm.cfg`.

Answer (score 2):

The default Java VM is set in your `jvm.cfg` file. On Windows this is in your Java folder in `C:\Program Files`, on Linux the path may vary.

On my Ubuntu 12.04 amd64 system with Oracle Java JDK7 installed via the [Webupd8 ppa](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html), the file is in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64`. For the default OpenJDK 6, the file is in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/jvm.cfg`. Note that you need the JDK and not just the JRE installed.

Edit the `jvm.cfg` that corresponds to your current default Java version (`sudo nano /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/jvm.cfg`). Switch `-server KNOWN` to `-server IGNORE` and `-client IGNORE` to `-client KNOWN`.

This will make the `-client flag` "known" to the java executable, and make it ignore the `-server flag`, thus making it the default.

The original file (client vm as default):

```
# Copyright (c) 2003, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
# ORACLE PROPRIETARY/CONFIDENTIAL. Use is subject to license terms.
#
# List of JVMs that can be used as an option to java, javac, etc.
# Order is important -- first in this list is the default JVM.
# NOTE that this both this file and its format are UNSUPPORTED and
# WILL GO AWAY in a future release.
#
# You may also select a JVM in an arbitrary location with the
# "-XXaltjvm=<jvm_dir>" option, but that too is unsupported
# and may not be available in a future release.
#
-server KNOWN
-client IGNORE
-hotspot ERROR
-classic WARN
-native ERROR
-green ERROR
```

Modified file (server vm as default):

```
# Copyright (c) 2003, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
# ORACLE PROPRIETARY/CONFIDENTIAL. Use is subject to license terms.
#
# List of JVMs that can be used as an option to java, javac, etc.
# Order is important -- first in this list is the default JVM.
# NOTE that this both this file and its format are UNSUPPORTED and
# WILL GO AWAY in a future release.
#
# You may also select a JVM in an arbitrary location with the
# "-XXaltjvm=<jvm_dir>" option, but that too is unsupported
# and may not be available in a future release.
#
#-server KNOWN
-server IGNORE
#-client IGNORE
-client KNOWN
-hotspot ERROR
-classic WARN
-native ERROR
-green ERROR
```

Now test to see if the change worked:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

[Source](http://keithlea.com/javabench/#servervm)

Comment: This is partially incorrect: it's the order that determines the default JVM, not KNOWN or IGNORE. (The comments in that file indicate this: "Order is important -- first in this list is the default JVM".) IGNORE just silently disables a VM option. Your original jvm.cfg uses server as the default, and has client silently disabled, probably because it isn't present.

Comment: This is the Ubuntu QA, no need for "On Windows do..." :)